# output one arrangement of n people everyone has k friends,

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

This is an interview question, given n people, output one arrangement that everyone has k friends.
n>k. it is possible that no answer, i.e. if both n and k are odd number, then no answer.
naive pick k friends for each people may not return a solution, i.e. n=6, k=4, you may end up 5 people friends with each other, and one left with no friends. What will be the fast algorithm for this question? and are there similar question?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange everyone in a circle.

- For even k, have everyone be friends with the people within k/2 spots from them.
- For odd k and even n, have everyone be friends with the people within (k-1)/2 spots from them and the person across from them.
- For odd k and odd n, there is no solution.